# Returning a variable from a different sub does not retain value

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Here I call a sub routine that will do some things in excel for me, and I'm looking to get `IQRef()` and `IQRngRef()` filled in:

```
    Dim IQRef() As Variant
    Dim IQRngRef() As Variant
    CaptureExcelReferences xlWB, pivotSheetName, IQRef, IQRngRef
```

Here is the Sub routine, it calls upon `CaptureIQRefsLocally` to fill in `IQRef()` and `IQRngRef()`

```
Private Sub CaptureExcelReferences(ByVal xlWB As Workbook, ByVal pivotSheetName As String, ByRef IQRef() As Variant, ByRef IQRngRef() As Variant)
    Dim ShRef As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ShRef = xlWB.Worksheets(pivotSheetName)

    Dim colNumb As Long
    colNumb = ShRef.Cells(1, ShRef.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ReDim IQRef(colNumb)
    ReDim IQRngRef(colNumb)

    Dim rowNumb As Long
    rowNumb = ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    CaptureIQRefsLocally ShRef, rowNumb, colNumb, IQRef, IQRngRef
    IdentifyRolesAndScoresRows IQRngRef, rowNumb
End Sub
```

Here is the Sub that actually fills in `IQRef()` and `IQRngRef()`

```
Private Sub CaptureIQRefsLocally(ByVal ShRef As Worksheet, ByVal rowNumb As Long, ByVal colNumb As Long, ByRef IQRef As Variant, ByRef IQRngRef As Variant)
    'capture IQ references in arrays. Values for column titles in IQRef and full column Ranges in IQRngRef.
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim alignIQNumbToArrayNumb
        For iCol = 1 To colNumb
            alignIQNumbToArrayNumb = iCol - 1
            Set IQRngRef(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(1, iCol), ShRef.Cells(rowNumb, iCol))
            IQRef(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = ShRef.Cells(1, iCol).Value
            'IsThisaKeyIQ IQRngref, IQRef
        Next iCol
End Sub
```

Everything works fine for `IQRef`, it gets filled in correctly and passes back to the main Sub fully and completely (Each array slot filled with a String from a single cell, so it returns a string for each slot.)

For `IQRngRef`, where each slot gets filled with a range, the results are not so good. In `CaptureIQRefsLocally` it gets filled in correctly and it passes the values back to `CaptureExcelReferences` correctly, it's even able to used in the following sub `IdentifyRolesAndScoresRows` correctly (it doesn't get modified in this sub at all, and the values are still correct when the values are returned)... But when it gets passed back to the main sub `IQRngRef` it's empty...ish. It looks like this:[image]

The reason this is happening (as I found out while I was typing this) is because I close the excel workbook and application right after this sub so I can go back to working in powerpoint (I just want to go into excel, get the information I need, store it in array and close it.) Is there any way to still store all the same values in the array and close the excel application?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to store the full address of the cell instead of a reference to it? The `.Address` method has an `External` parameter which, when true, returns (as a string) the range address with the workbook name and worksheet name that the range resides in.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
IQRngRef(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = Application.Transpose(ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(1, iCol), ShRef.Cells(rowNumb, iCol)).Value)
```

This way each IQRngRef slot will store a 1D array